# Looking for resources on Dynamic Generalized Assignment problem

Tags: discrete-optimization, operations-research

I'm trying to find previous research on the dynamized version of the Generalized Assignment Problem. That is, how to efficiently maintain an optimal solution in the case where existing workers can be fired and new ones hired.

Some additional constraints from my specific problem are that each worker can only be feasibly assigned to some subset of tasks, all workers take up the same space on all tasks they can be feasibly assigned to, and individual workers have equal competencies at all tasks they can be assigned to.

The problem is to assign n workers to m tasks, maximizing the total competency of all assigned workers. Each worker j has a competency $s_j$ and a set of tasks $f_j \subseteq \{1, ..., m\}$ to which it can be assigned. The number of workers assigned to task i must be less than or equal to the capacity of the task $c_i$. $x_{ij}$ is 1 if worker j is assigned to task i and 0 otherwise.
Formally, the following:

maximize $\sum_{j=1}^n s_{j} \sum_{i \in f_j} x_{ij}$

subject to $\sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{i' \in f_j} 1[i' == i] x_{ij} \le c_i, i=1, \ldots, m$;

$\sum_{i \in f_j} x_{ij} \leq 1, j=1, \ldots, n$;

$x_{ij} \in \{0,1\}, j=1, \ldots, n, \quad i \in f_j$

The problem is dynamic because the set of n workers can change over time, with new workers being fired or old ones fired. I want to efficiently maintain the optimal assignment as these changes happen.

If anyone can point me in the direction of some prior work on this, it'd be much appreciated (or at the very least a better search term for these types of dynamically-updating assignment problems than "dynamic", since that just turns up a lot of dynamic programming solutions to the static problem).

Comment: Why not just write $s_i$ if it depends only on $i$?

Comment: That's a good point. I was adapting the notation from the more general GAP, but you're right that I don't need the second index for s. Edited the question.

Comment: You rewrote it as $s_j$, which yields a much easier problem than $s_i$.

Comment: Right, the competencies are the same across all tasks i for each worker j. The difficulty is in choosing a data structure to maintain this optimal score efficiently as workers are added and removed. Do you know what I could search to find dynamic GAP algorithms/data structures?

Comment: I don't know any such data structures.  Notice that your objective function reduces to a constant: $\sum_i \sum_j s_j x_{ij} = \sum_j s_j \sum_i x_{ij} = \sum_j s_j (1)  = \sum_j s_j$.

Comment: Right, the constraint on x was incorrect. It should've been $\sum_{i=1}^m x_{ij} \leq 1, j=1, \ldots, n$. Workers do not have to be assigned to a task. Is there a more general term for dynamically updating optimization problems? The Data Structures class that I'm taking (which this is a project proposal for) refers to them as Dynamic problems, but that runs into the aforementioned name collision with Dynamic Programming.

Comment: I recommend eliminating $w_{ij}$ by instead omitting $x_{ij}$ if $w_{ij}=c_i+1$.  That is, use a sparse index set of allowable $(i,j)$ pairs instead of the full Cartesian product $\{1,\dots,m\} \times \{1,\dots,n\}$.

Comment: Something like the above edit? I added a set $f_j$ of tasks that worker j can be assigned to, restricting the set of allowable pairs, and eliminated w. Makes the capacity sum a little messier and I'm not sure I exactly did what you suggested.

Comment: Yes, that looks correct, but you can simplify the capacity constraint by introducing a set $g_i$ and replacing the double sum with $\sum_{j\in g_i} x_{ij}$.